# formatDate not working as expected

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, momentjs, fullcalendar-3

This is my first FullCalendar project.
I clicked on May 13.

I format the date as follows :

```html
                dayClick: function (date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
                    var startFix = moment($.fullCalendar.formatDate(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD'));
                    $('#eventDate').val(startFix);
```

But eventDate  shows "Sat May 13 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0700" instead of 'YYYY-MM-DD' format. Any idea what I am doing wrong?
Thanks, Peter

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
moment(yourDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Yes, that is perfect. Thanks!